# PHP: while loop stops when adding data from function

Tags: php, while-loop

The following code shows the name of the customer in a line with all the items he/she has purchased in lines below the name line.

As you will see, in the items purchased line I also print the item's price which I get from the getPrice function.

And here's the problem, the first query, the customers query, retrieves several rows of data but as soon as I call the getPrice function I get just the first row.

If instead of calling the function I give price just a value, everything goes right.

Taking this into account, I have changed the getPrice function query, thinking it could be wrong but the problem persists .. the while loop prints just one row.

Any ideas on what is going wrong? What can I try? I’m stuck :(

Thanks !!

```
<?php

$query1  = "SELECT * FROM Customers"; //this retrieves several rows of data
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

$flag = -999;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{

    if ($row["id"] != $flag) 
    {

        $content .="<span>".$row["lastName"].", ".$row["Name"]." </span><br />";
        $flag = $row["id"];
    }

    $content .=("Item purchased: " .$row["item"]."Price: ".getPrice($row["ItemID"])."<br />");


    $content .="</br></br>";
}                


function getPrice ($itemID)
{

    $query2  = "SELECT Price FROM Items WHERE ItemID= '".$itemID."'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

    if($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        return $row2[0];
    } 
}

echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Please post the table structure and some sample records, preferably in form of `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...` sql statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use while instead of if in getPrice function

```
function getPrice ($itemID)
{
//Changed this line
$query2="SELECT Price FROM Items WHERE ItemID= '".$itemID."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    return $row2[0];
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPrice ($itemID)
{
    //Changed this line
    $query2="SELECT Price FROM Items WHERE ItemID= '".$itemID."'";//;was missing
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

    if($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        return $row2[0];
    } 
}
```

Comment: My error when copying the code, in my script is correct .. thanks